# Ms Access 2013 crashing on Windows 10

Tags: vba, ms-access, windows-10, ms-access-2013

I have a database originally built in Ms Access 2010. Part of the VBA code allows users to extract data and save to their machine. This employs [Ken Getz's code](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-access/help-with-vba-concerning-the-opensave-as-dialog/970bbf7b-28e9-4568-9b4f-50cc0f3d3d46) for earlier versions and `Application.FileDialog()` for later versions.

One user is running 64 bit Windows 10 with Access 2013 (32 bit) installed.

When trying to run the code on this machine Access crashes without any error messages and restarts.

There are checks in the code for 64 or 32 bit versions and for the version of VB (6 or 7).

Given the lack of error messages I'm not sure how to troubleshoot or fix this.

Here's the sub which calls Ken Getz's code depending on version:

```
 Dim queryYear As Variant

'Function to export data to location of users choice.  Exports TWO queries to same workbook.
'Survey name is automatically detected from the control button used
'(must be changed to BaMN_ for example) as previous export only used one query.
'Year is derived from the combobox value on [Extract Data] form, null value defaults to all years.

Function exportData_Click()

    'Checks VBA version. This function will only work on 7+
    #If VBA7 Then

    'Code is running in the new VBA7 editor

    'Declare Variables used by both 32 and 64 bit versions
    Dim strSaveFileName As String 'both
    Dim The_Year As Variant 'both
    Dim ctlCurrentControl As Control 'both
    Dim surveyName As String 'both
    Dim allData As String 'both
    Dim effort As String 'both
    Dim fileYear As String 'both

    'Get the name of the control button clicked (corresponds to query name to be run)
    Set ctlCurrentControl = Screen.ActiveControl
    surveyName = ctlCurrentControl.Name
    allData = surveyName & "AllData"
    effort = surveyName & "Effort_Export"

    'Get combobox value and assign relavent values to The_Year
    The_Year = Forms![Extract Data]!Extract_Year.value

    'Change the year from a variant to what we need in the SQL
    If The_Year Like "20*" Then

        The_Year = CInt(The_Year)
        fileYear = The_Year

    Else:
        The_Year = "*"
        fileYear = "All"


    End If

    'Set queryYear variable
    setYear (The_Year)

    'If block to deal with both 32 and 64 bit versions.
    #If Win64 Then

        'Code is running in 64-bit version of Microsoft Office
        MsgBox ("Running 64 bit version")

        'Declare 64 bit only variables
        Dim f As FileDialog

        'Open the Save as Dialog to choose location of query save
        Set f = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
        f.AllowMultiSelect = False
        f.ButtonName = "Save"
        f.Title = "Save As"
        strSaveFileName = surveyName & fileYear & "_output.xlsx"
        f.InitialFileName = strSaveFileName
        f.Show

        'End of 64 bit code

        #Else

        'Code is running in 32-bit version of Microsoft Office
        MsgBox ("Running 32 bit version")

        'Declare
        Dim strFilter As String '32

        'Open the Save as Dialog to choose location of query save for 32 bit
        strFilter = ahtAddFilterItem("Excel Files (*.xlsx)", "*.xlsx")
        strSaveFileName = ahtCommonFileOpenSave( _
                                        openFile:=False, _
                                        Filter:=strFilter, _
                        Flags:=ahtOFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT Or ahtOFN_READONLY)
    #End If

    'Export functions for different survey cases
    If surveyName Like "*O*_" Then
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, allData, strSaveFileName

    ElseIf surveyName Like "*DA_" Then

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, surveyName & "Occ_export", strSaveFileName
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, surveyName & "Trees_export", strSaveFileName
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, surveyName & "RepTree_export", strSaveFileName
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, surveyName & "Habitat_export", strSaveFileName
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, surveyName & "TPole_export", strSaveFileName

    Else
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, allData, strSaveFileName
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, effort, strSaveFileName
    End If

    #Else

    'Code is running in VBA version 6 or earlier
    MsgBox ("Only available on MS Access 2007 and above")

    #End If



End Function
'Function to set queryYear used in data extraction queries
Public Function setYear(The_Year As Variant)

 queryYear = The_Year

End Function

'Function to get queryYear used in data extraction queries
Function getYear()

   getYear = queryYear

End Function
```

Comment: have you added error handling to that on the link?

Comment: I don't understand why you don't use `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)` for everyone. According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa195878(v=office.11).aspx it was introduced in Access 2003 - surely your Win32 users don't use an earlier version than that?

Comment: I was having difficulty allowing the user to choose a filename using `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)`. I seem to remember I had to hard code it. If you know a way of allowing them to make their own filenames then I can switch it over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using MS Access' [FileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196794.aspx) property but specify *folder picker* as [dialog type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865284.aspx). As far as I know, this should be compliant on any PC (32/64-bit version or Office 2003-2016 version). The somewhat dated link you use concerns the Open/Save Dialog box and not the File/Folder browser.

Once you obtain the folder name, simply concatenate with your Excel file's base name, conditional on export type: *surveyName*, *allData*, or *effort*.

```
Function exportData_Click()

    ' Declare Variables        
    Dim strSaveFileName As String
    Dim The_Year As Variant
    Dim ctlCurrentControl As Control
    Dim surveyName As String, allData As String, effort As String
    Dim fileYear As String

    Dim fd As Object
    Const msoFileDialogFolderPicker = 4
    Dim strFolderPath

    ' Get the name of the control button clicked (corresponds to query name to be run)
    Set ctlCurrentControl = Screen.ActiveControl
    surveyName = ctlCurrentControl.Name
    allData = surveyName & "AllData"
    effort = surveyName & "Effort_Export"

    ' Get combobox value and assign relavent values to The_Year
    The_Year = Forms![Extract Data]!Extract_Year.Value

    ' Change the year from a variant to what we need in the SQL
    If The_Year Like "20*" Then
        The_Year = CInt(The_Year)
        fileYear = The_Year
    Else:
        The_Year = "*"
        fileYear = "All"
    End If

    ' Set queryYear variable
    setYear (The_Year)

    ' Folder Pick Dialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With fd
        .Title = "Browse for folder to export queries"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Clear
        If .Show = -1 Then
            strFolderPath = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            'The user pressed Cancel.
            MsgBox "No folder Selected", vbExclamation
            strFolderPath = Null
            Set fd = Nothing
            Exit Function
        End If
    End With

    Set fd = Nothing

    ' Export functions for different survey cases
    If surveyName Like "*O*_" Then
        strSaveFileName = strFolderPath & "\" & allData & ".xlsx"
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, allData, strSaveFileName

    ElseIf surveyName Like "*DA_" Then
        strSaveFileName = strFolderPath & "\" & surveyName & ".xlsx"
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, surveyName & "Occ_export", strSaveFileName
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, surveyName & "Trees_export", strSaveFileName
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, surveyName & "RepTree_export", strSaveFileName
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, surveyName & "Habitat_export", strSaveFileName
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, surveyName & "TPole_export", strSaveFileName

    Else
        strSaveFileName = strFolderPath & "\" & allData & ".xlsx"
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, allData, strSaveFileName
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, effort, strSaveFileName
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks parfait. This worked and has been tested on a number of different installs / versions/ OS's. The one thing that bugs me is that the user still doesn't have the ability to enter their own file name. In addition if they are saving the same output to the same folder it will overwrite without any warning. As such I've hard coded date and time of export to the filename to keep them unique(ish).

Comment: Great! Glad I can help. For entering their own filename, use VBA's [InputBox](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/InputBox-Function-17821927-28b7-4350-b7f1-4786575314d9) which prompts user with input that you can concatenate to *strSaveFileName*. This will come after the file dialog.

Comment: I'm quite keen on hard coding the files now they have a date and time stamp. At least everyone in the organisation will be speaking the same language when it comes to exports. Good to know the alternative though.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of checks.

Check References - are any marked as MISSING?

You might have to reference the Microsoft Office Object library that exists on user computer - is it 64 bit Office with 32 bit MS-Access?

Obvious question - any compile errors?

> EDIT - Update suggestions

You're calling `aht_apiGetOpenFileName` in your question that requires the `tagOpenFilename` structure, but in your code you're showing that you pass multiple parameters

Comment: None of the references are marked as MISSING.

It's 32 bit Office installed on a 64 bit machine. The user still has Office 2007 installed.

No compile errors.

Comment: Can you pinpoint a function or line of code that causes the crash? Or does it crash on loading? Before I distribute, the one thing I always do with my Access 2010 databases (never used 2013), is to decompile the database, recompile it, compact and repair and save the file - I used to get random crashes on user computers before I did this. Are you distributing accde or accdb?

Comment: Distributing accdb. I've just tried the compact and repair. Still no luck. It doesn't crash on loading. It is when the "extract data" sub is run (via a button click on the dashboard). It should export a query to xlsx and give the user the save dialog to choose save location. Once the button is clicked we're just getting a "Access has stopped working, windows is looking for a solution". No solution is found and then it closes itself.

Comment: Can you post the sub? Have you tried the decompile/recompile/compact step?

Comment: I've added the sub to the original question.

Comment: Does it actually crash even before Msgbox shows Win64 message?

Comment: No the msg box (for 32 bit in this user's case) appears and it crashes after okaying out of it. I put the msg boxes in as a crude debug.

Comment: Ahh okay - so you don't know exactly what line is causing it but it's in the 32 bit section and likely on the `ahtCommonFileOpenSave` call - how is that API function declared or is it part of a class? ** (edit ... stepping out for an hour)**

Comment: I altered the Ken Getz code (see link in original post) to include PtrSafe in declarations e.g. `Declare PtrSafe Function aht_apiGetOpenFileName Lib "comdlg32.dll" _
() '    Alias "GetOpenFileNameA" (OFN As tagOPENFILENAME) As Boolean`
Other than that it is as the original. **(edit ... in a cloud forest in Honduras... generator going of for a while)

Comment: You're calling `ahtCommonFileOpenSave` in your question but showing me `aht_apiGetOpenFileName` above - in either case both require the tagOpenFilename structure - in your question you're showing that you pass multiple parameters instead

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114980/discussion-between-oliver-burdekin-and-dbmitch).

Comment: Sure - let me know when. I'm off grid too. Getting dark here